# The webpage cannot be found - This error (HTTP 400 Bad Request) means that this program was able to connect to the web server

Tags: java, html, mysql, api, eclipse-luna

I have this table in MySQL:

```
CREATE TABLE `catheterization`(
 `catheterization_formnum` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `national_healthcare_patient_id` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
 `examination_date` date DEFAULT NULL,
 `description` text,
 `date1` date DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`catheterization_formnum`)
```

and I'm trying to make an API
Also I have this class in eclipse:

```
/**
 * Servlet implementation class InsertData
 */
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
@WebServlet("/InsertCatheterization")
public class InsertCatheterization extends EHRSEservlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
     */
    public InsertCatheterization() {
        super();
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    }

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        HashMap<String, String> jsonData;
        // If there was a problem parsing the JSON data
        if((jsonData = parseSTJSON(getJSONString(request), response)) == null){
            return;
        }

        //Open the session
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        session.beginTransaction();


        //Create new admission data object
        Catheterization cath = new Catheterization();

        cath.setCatheterizationFormnum(jsonData.get("catheterizationFormnum"));
 cath.setNationalHealthcarePatientId(jsonData.get("nationalHealthcarePatientId"));
        cath.setExaminationDate(toDate(jsonData.get("examinationDate")));
        cath.setDescription(jsonData.get("description"));
        cath.setDate1(toDate(jsonData.get("date1")));

      //Save the new data in the database
        try{ System.out.print("hhhH1"); //just print something for know if run the try
            session.save(cath);// the program stop here
            System.out.print("hhhH");
            //Update the time of the last change in the patients data
            Date curDate = new Date();
            System.out.print("hhh");
            //updateDateOfPatientDataChange(session, curDate, patientData.getPatientId());
            //Commit the transaction
            session.getTransaction().commit();
            session.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            session.close();
            setErrorMessage(response, 400, "Bad Request", "Could not insert data. Check the data given as input.");
            return;
        }

        JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject();
        jObj.put("catheterization_formnum", cath.getCatheterizationFormnum());
        //Set the success message with the results
        setSuccessMessage(response,jObj);

    }

}
```

My inserttext.html file is:

```
<div class="container">
    <form action="InsertCatheterization" method="POST">
        <input type='text' name='data'
            value='{"catheterizationFormnum":"1", "nationalHealthcarePatientId":"9", "examinationDate":"2017-03-05", "description":"ok", "date1":"2017-03-05" }' />
        <input type="submit" value="INSERT CATHETERIZATION">
    </form>
</div>
```

when Im trying to run this html file the compiler stop at the session.save(cath) and I don't Know why.

Comment: You shock the exception in the catch : `catch(Exception e){session.close(); setErrorMessage(response, 400, "Bad Request", "Could not insert data. Check the data given as input.");return;}` . Trace it and you would have some clues.

Comment: Can you post the exception stacktrace?